# Add Host Server to SCVMM Server

Tags: hyper-v

When I try to add a host server to a scvmm server i got this message

Access has been denied while contacting the server .

1. Verify that the specified user account has administrative privileges on .
2. Verify that DCOM access, launch, and activation permissions are enabled on  for the Administrators group. Use dcomcnfg.exe to modify permissions, and then try the operation again.

ID: 406

The user account has administrative privileges on both servers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It requires the administrative privileges in group of that domain, in which that host / VM is present.
Please check the permission for that user on domains.